# How to properly implement getter/setter functionality, either for both a property's `get` and `set`, or for two methods and a property's `get`?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, getter-setter, encapsulation

I have a logic that need to reactively run some function

if a `this.variableName` is changed inside or outside the class

the problem is with this logic, getter doesn't work, and I get `undefined`.

not only this, but also maximum stack error.

because is like: set the `this` inside the setter, that re-set the `this`, that re-call another time the setter, that set the this, and so on... (but this isn't what I meant)

---

Semplified version, without parameters, and so, just the minimal example of the bug.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
     this.isOn = false;
  }

  set isOn(value) {
    this.isOn = value;
    // another functions that do stuff. you can put here a bunch of console.logs if you want just for the demo
  }

  // the idea is another, but i will show you the simpliest method, I could imagine, just to make you get the idea
  
  turnOn() {
     this.isOn = true;
  }
 
  turnOff() {
     this.isOn = false;
  }

  // using this approach, 
  // I don't need to copy paste the same functions in this 2 methods, 
  // so I just need to care about the var, 
  // without using a imperative approach, 
  // but a declarative approach
}
```

---

> I know we can use _isOn,
>
>  but this is literally the opposite of what we want,
>
> because I want the setter to be the same name of the getter,
>
>  and still do the logic on setter.
>
>
>  hope you get my idea. thanks

Comment: Impossible to do. When you run `this.isOn =` you are referencing the setter, not the variable

Comment: Use a private class property `this.#isOn`. Is there any reason to not use `_isOn`?

Comment: @Konrad I dont want to use it because at the end, getter and setter will have different names

Comment: Getter and setter would be interfaces for the internal variable. If you name both getter and setter `isOn`, then both would have the same name. Or do you mean that you want the getter/setter to have the same name as the internal variable? If so, then Konrad's comment applies.

Comment: @OskarGrosser basically I need somehow reactivity something like the frameworks, but only with simple oop js. if I change a this.isOn, then it need to do some calculation or run some function then set the value of this.isOn, and the easily accessed. the result I want is to not repeat the same function over and over in  all my methods for every this.isOn changed. maybe is not possible, but using # or _ don't solve my issue. based on konrad answer, the methods dont run the setter but only change

Comment: 1/2 ... There is anyhow a design flaw, one either uses a get/set solution for what gets exposed as a single public property (here `isOn`) or one does use two differently named public methods (here `turnOn`/`turnOff`). And since both solutions implement at least `set` functionality, both need to achieve this by changing/controlling a somehow *private* value (be it a [private instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_instance_fields) or a local variable or maybe even a `WeakMap` based solution).

Comment: @stackdeveloper ... 2/2 ... What the OP's code so far tries to achieve, and also what the accepted answer offers, is not necessary. Already having two explicit setters like `turnOn`/`turnOff` which both do change a public `isOn` property is utterly wrong, at least it's error prone. Worse, `isOn` already has been implemented via `get`/`set`. Either go with the latter or with the former and either variant implemented properly. Do not mix both; it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [private properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

```js
class MyClass {
  #isOn = false;

  set isOn(value) {
    this.#isOn = value;
  }
  
  get isOn() {
    return this.#isOn
  }

  turnOn() {
     this.isOn = true;
  }
 
  turnOff() {
     this.isOn = false;
  }
}

const x = new MyClass

x.isOn = true

console.log(x.isOn)

// This will throw an error:
// console.log(x.#isOn)
```

Comment: sorry, but is isn't what I want. I want somehow to have same name using set, and get. I hope someone have a trick on how to exploit this, and make actually work, because in in your example: turnOn or turnOff we still use #, which don't run that functions, but just change the value

Comment: In `turnOff` and `turnOff` you can use `this.isOn` directly

Comment: edit the answer and I will upvote your answer, and accept it. maybe is what I want, let's see

Comment: You should use *either* the setter *or* `turnOn/Off` methods, not both.

Comment: @Bergi I think op wanted to run a function when an internal variable changes. It could be done using a proxy I guess

Comment: @Konrad No proxy. The code of that function (or the function call) should be placed in the setter or the methods - the OP already has a comment to that effect in their code.

Answer (score 1):

From my above comments ...

> There is anyhow a design flaw, one either uses a `get`/`set` solution for what gets exposed as a single public property (here `isOn`) or one does use two differently named public methods (here `turnOn`/`turnOff`). And since both solutions implement at least `set` functionality, both need to achieve this by changing/controlling a somehow **private** value (be it a [private instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields) or a local variable or maybe even a WeakMap based solution).
> What the OP's code so far tries to achieve, and also what the accepted answer offers, is not necessary. Already having two explicit setters like `turnOn`/`turnOff` which both do change a public `isOn` property is utterly wrong, at least it's error prone. Worse, `isOn` already has been implemented via `get`/`set`. Either go with the latter or with the former and either variant implemented properly. Do not mix both; it does not make any sense.

Taking into account the above said, there are following two code examples.

The **1st** one focusses on the **`get`/`set`** implementation of a **single public `isOn` property**, whereas the **2nd** chooses the approach of **explicit methods** like **`turnOn`/`turnOff`** in combination with a **single `get`** for the **sole public `isOn` property**.

Each approach offers **two implementations**, one choosing **private instance field(s)** and the other one being based on **encapsulated local variables**.

```js
class SwitchStateWithGetSetAndPrivateFields {
  #isOn;
  #handleSwitchChange;

  constructor(switchDefault = false, onSwitchChange) {
    this.#isOn = Boolean(switchDefault);
    this.#handleSwitchChange = onSwitchChange;
  }
  set isOn(value) {
    if ('boolean' === typeof value) {

      if (this.#isOn !== value) {

        this.#isOn = value;
        this.#handleSwitchChange(this);
      }
    } else {
      throw new TypeError('The assigned value needs to be a boolean type.');
    }
  }
  get isOn() {
    return this.#isOn;
  }
}

class SwitchStateWithGetSetAndLocalValues {

  constructor(switchDefault = false, handleSwitchChange) {
    let isOn = Boolean(switchDefault);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'isOn', {
      set(value) {
        if ('boolean' === typeof value) {

          if (isOn !== value) {

            isOn = value;
            handleSwitchChange(this);
          }
        } else {
          throw new TypeError('The assigned value needs to be a boolean type.');
        }
      },
      get() {
        return isOn;
      },
      enumerable: true,
    });
  }
}

function logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype(fieldtype, instance) {
  console.log({ [`${ fieldtype }IsOn`]: instance.isOn });
}

const onOffStateRadio =
  new SwitchStateWithGetSetAndPrivateFields(
    true, logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype.bind(null, 'radio')
  );
const onOffStateText =
  new SwitchStateWithGetSetAndLocalValues(
    false, logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype.bind(null, 'text')
  );

document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const booleanMap = {
      'true': true,
      'false': false,
      '': false,
    };
    const formElements = evt.currentTarget.elements;

    const radioValue = booleanMap[formElements['is_on'].value];
    const textValue = booleanMap[formElements['is_on_text'].value.trim().toLowerCase()];

    onOffStateRadio.isOn = radioValue;
    onOffStateText.isOn = textValue;
  });

logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype('radio', onOffStateRadio);
logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype('text', onOffStateText);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 40%; }
fieldset { margin: 5px 0; }
form > label { display: block; margin: 5px 0 10px 14px; }
form > label > input, form > button { float: right; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%; width: 59%; }
```

```html
<form>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>isOn:</legend>
    <label>
      <span>true</span>
      <input type="radio" name="is_on" value="true" checked/>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>false</span>
      <input type="radio" name="is_on" value="false"/>
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <label>
    <span>isOn:</span>
    <input type="text" name="is_on_text" placeholder="whatever"/>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">apply values</button>
</form>
```

```js
class SwitchStateWithExplicitMethodsSingleGetAndPrivateFields {
  #isOn;
  #handleSwitchChange;

  constructor(switchDefault = false, onSwitchChange) {
    this.#isOn = Boolean(switchDefault);
    this.#handleSwitchChange = onSwitchChange;
  }
  get isOn() {
    return this.#isOn;
  }

  turnOn() {
    if (this.#isOn === false) {

      this.#isOn = true;
      this.#handleSwitchChange(this);
    }
  }
  turnOff() {
    if (this.#isOn === true) {

      this.#isOn = false;
      this.#handleSwitchChange(this);
    }
  }
}

class SwitchStateWithExplicitMethodsSingleGetAndLocalValues {

  constructor(switchDefault = false, handleSwitchChange) {
    let isOn = Boolean(switchDefault);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'isOn', {
      get() {
        return isOn;
      },
      enumerable: true,
    });

    this.turnOn = function turnOn() {
      if (isOn === false) {

        isOn = true;
        handleSwitchChange(this);
      }
    }
    this.turnOff = function turnOff() {
      if (isOn === true) {

        isOn = false;
        handleSwitchChange(this);
      }
    }
  }
}

function logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype(fieldtype, instance) {
  console.log({ [`${ fieldtype }IsOn`]: instance.isOn });
}

const onOffStateRadio =
  new SwitchStateWithExplicitMethodsSingleGetAndPrivateFields(
    true, logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype.bind(null, 'radio')
  );
const onOffStateText =
  new SwitchStateWithExplicitMethodsSingleGetAndLocalValues(
    false, logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype.bind(null, 'text')
  );

document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const booleanMap = {
      'true': true,
      'false': false,
      '': false,
    };
    const formElements = evt.currentTarget.elements;

    const radioValue = booleanMap[formElements['is_on'].value];
    const textValue = booleanMap[formElements['is_on_text'].value.trim().toLowerCase()];

    onOffStateRadio[radioValue && 'turnOn' || 'turnOff']();
    onOffStateText[textValue && 'turnOn' || 'turnOff']();
  });

logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype('radio', onOffStateRadio);
logSwitchStateOfBoundFieldtype('text', onOffStateText);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 40%; }
fieldset { margin: 5px 0; }
form > label { display: block; margin: 5px 0 10px 14px; }
form > label > input, form > button { float: right; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; min-height: 100%; width: 59%; }
```

```html
<form>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>isOn:</legend>
    <label>
      <span>true</span>
      <input type="radio" name="is_on" value="true" checked/>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>false</span>
      <input type="radio" name="is_on" value="false"/>
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <label>
    <span>isOn:</span>
    <input type="text" name="is_on_text" placeholder="whatever"/>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">apply values</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @stackdeveloper ... The OP might have a look at the late provided, above answer and code examples.

Answer (score -2):

As [Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad) has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297983/setter-js-cant-set-same-variable-this-in-javascript-setter-and-getter-need-to#comment136271594_77297983), you cannot reference two distinct objects with one identifier. Instead, you could [use internal members when referencing from inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298049/13561410).

Alternatively, if we separate the data from the class, we could instance two objects: One where changing the data (e.g. through a proxy) has a side-effect, and the other that changes directly.

Example:

```js
class MyClass {
  #data = null;

  constructor(data) {
    this.#data = data;
  }
  
  set isOn(value) {
    this.#data.isOn = value;
  }
  get isOn() {
    return this.#data.isOn;
  }
  
  turnOn() {
    this.isOn = true;
  }

  turnOff() {
    this.isOn = false;
  }
}

const data = {
  isOn: false
};

const dataProxy = new Proxy(data, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === "isOn") {
      console.log("get side-effect");
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
  set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
    if (prop === "isOn") {
      console.log("set side-effect");
    }
    return Reflect.set(...arguments);
  }
});

const directObject = new MyClass(data);
const indirectObject = new MyClass(dataProxy);

console.log("Direct isOn:", directObject.isOn);
console.log("Direct turnOn()");
directObject.turnOn();

console.log("Indirect isOn:", indirectObject.isOn);
console.log("Indirect turnOff()");
indirectObject.turnOff();
```

Here, we have two objects of class `MyClass` that act on the same data, one of them through a proxy. The proxied `MyClass`'s methods will cause side-effects.

This allows for one implementation for the behaviour (one `MyClass` class), and one set of data. The proxy allows for controlling access and (as you wanted) causing side-effects when accessing.